# In magento 2 javascript , How i can wait till a component/node initialize then i can excute my code?

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent, registry, async

How to wait till components exists in registry . I want to wait till global component "messages" initialize then I can add error/success message.

```
// view/frontend/templates/messages.phtml
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                        "messages": {
                            "component": "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
</script>
```

I have try 'Magento_Ui/js/lib/view/utils/async' but it's seam don't work. It does not run in debugger 1

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/view/utils/async'
], function ($, customer_data) {
    $.async('> *', 'messages', function(node){
        // debugger 1;
        customer_data.set('messages',{'test':'your cookie have expires, you have to login again','type':'success'});
    })
}
```

How I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

1.Make sure you have a custom JavaScript file that contains the code you provided. Let's call it **custom_messages.js.** This file should be placed in your theme's or module's **requirejs-config.js** file.

2.In your theme or module's **requirejs-config.js**, add the following code:

```
  var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'customMessages': 'path/to/custom_messages' // Path to your custom_messages.js file
        }
    }
};
```

3.Update your custom_messages.js file with the corrected code.

```
     define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Magento_Ui/js/lib/view/utils/async'
], function ($, customerData, async) {
    async.asyncRendered('.page.messages', function () {
        customerData.set('messages', {'test': 'Your cookie has expired. You need to log in again.', 'type': 'success'});
    });
});
```

In the above code, we use the **asyncRendered** function from the **async** module to wait for the element with the class .**page.messages** to be rendered on the page. Once the element is rendered, we set the desired message using the **customerData.** set function.

4.Make sure the **messages.phtml** file is present in your theme or module's templates directory with the correct path: **view/frontend/templates/messages.phtml.**

After following these steps, the **custom_messages.js** file should be loaded and executed after the **messages** component is initialized, allowing you to add your error/success message successfully.

**Note**: Make sure to clear the Magento cache and deploy the static content after making any changes to JavaScript files or the requirejs-config.js file.

Comment: async.asyncRendered ?
I can not find this function in source page

Answer (score 0):

To wait until a global component like "messages" is initialized in Magento 2 and then add error/success messages, you can use the following approach:

1. Define a custom JavaScript file (e.g., `custom-messages.js`) and include it in your theme or module.
2. In your `custom-messages.js` file, define a function that waits for the component to be initialized using the `Magento_Ui/js/lib/view/utils/async` module.

   ```javascript
   define([
       'jquery',
       'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
       'Magento_Ui/js/lib/view/utils/async'
   ], function ($, customerData, async) {
       async('messages').done(function (messagesComponent) {
           // Add your error/success messages here
           var messages = {
               test: 'Your cookie has expired. You need to log in again.',
               type: 'success'
           };
           customerData.set('messages', messages);
       });
   });
   ```
3. Make sure to include the `custom-messages.js` file in your template or layout file. For example, in your `.phtml` template file:

   ```html
   <script type="text/javascript">
       require(['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/core/app'], function ($, app) {
           $(document).ready(function () {
               app.load({
                   'custom-messages': 'Vendor_Module/js/custom-messages'
               });
           });
       });
   </script>
   ```

   Replace `'Vendor_Module'` with the appropriate vendor and module names.

By following these steps, your custom JavaScript file will wait until the "messages" component is initialized and then add error/success messages using the `customer-data` module. Make sure to clear the cache and deploy the static content after adding the custom JavaScript file.

Note: Ensure that the `messages` component is included and initialized in your XML layout files or templates correctly.

Comment: 'Magento_Ui/js/core/app' don't have function load. Is your answer from chatgpt ?

Answer (score 0):

Offical Devdoc have the anwser https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_uiregistry.html

```
registry.get('componentName', function (component) {
    debugger;
});
```

p/s : i found the same question : [Magento 2 : Run/Execute Javascript after KnockoutJS has rendered all elements](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159427/magento-2-run-execute-javascript-after-knockoutjs-has-rendered-all-elements)